# optimization of unused properties of object by JVM / Compiler

Tags: java, optimization, jvm

My class contains few properties which never used anywhere (This is a DEMO of my real scenario). I heard that JVM optimized our Java code.

Does JVM / Compiler optimize / remove unused properties of an object?

```
public class A {
   private int unused1 = 100;// never called anywhere inside object
   public int unused2 = 999;// never called anywhere in the application 
}
```

I know that I need to study hard about JVM, Compiler and optimization. But the answer needed because within a short period I have to decide whether I will delete all(as much as possible) unused variable manually from a large codebase(about 10,000 java files) or just depend on JVM optimization.

Expecting some interesting and fruitful suggestions.

Comment: In general it is a kind of code smell. And seeing no warning markers in an IDE is nice. Also a tool like findbugs will detect such cases too. So a clean-up really is (1) unproblematic, (2) allows easier reading of code. Unused variables cause just minor overhead in general. But still. Maybe the wrong variable was used etcetera.

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks for your comment like a good answer.

Comment: The `javac` does almost no optimization, however the `JIT` could optimize this away at run time. Before you think about CPU efficiency, you should think about developer efficiency.  How easy is it to maintain code which portions of it don't do anything?

Comment: @PeterLawrey thank you very much for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No unfortunately their is no such magic hopefully, you have no other choice but to clean up your code using tools like [`PMD`](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) or [`FindBugs`](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) that will help you to detect such kind of issues and many more.

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge

Comment: So far your answer is the best and I UPVOTED. I'm just waiting for some interesting solutions(if they even come yet!). After that I'll definitely check my answer.

Comment: Please dont take it otherwise. Sometimes people loose their interest when they saw that it has an answer already as accepted. I just posted my question,So expecting more idea from experts.

Comment: no no don't worry I take it well, your answer is totally valid, I understand so enjoy :-)

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: No, the JVM compiler (javac) will not optimise out unused variables.

Let's have a look at the bytecode the javac compiler produces.

Using this as a test class:

```
public class Test {

    private int test = 5;
    private int test2 = 10;
    private String aString = "HelloWorld";
}
```

Produces:

```
Classfile /C:/Users/Huw/Desktop/Test.class


Last modified 19-Apr-2016; size 331 bytes
  MD5 checksum 1c49b13d1d5d8a2c52924b20753122af
  Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #7.#19         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Fieldref           #6.#20         // Test.test:I
   #3 = Fieldref           #6.#21         // Test.test2:I
   #4 = String             #22            // HelloWorld
   #5 = Fieldref           #6.#23         // Test.aString:Ljava/lang/String;
   #6 = Class              #24            // Test
   #7 = Class              #25            // java/lang/Object
   #8 = Utf8               test
   #9 = Utf8               I
  #10 = Utf8               test2
  #11 = Utf8               aString
  #12 = Utf8               Ljava/lang/String;
  #13 = Utf8               <init>
  #14 = Utf8               ()V
  #15 = Utf8               Code
  #16 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #17 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #18 = Utf8               Test.java
  #19 = NameAndType        #13:#14        // "<init>":()V
  #20 = NameAndType        #8:#9          // test:I
  #21 = NameAndType        #10:#9         // test2:I
  #22 = Utf8               HelloWorld
  #23 = NameAndType        #11:#12        // aString:Ljava/lang/String;
  #24 = Utf8               Test
  #25 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
{
  public Test();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0
         5: iconst_5
         6: putfield      #2                  // Field test:I
         9: aload_0
        10: bipush        10
        12: putfield      #3                  // Field test2:I
        15: aload_0
        16: ldc           #4                  // String HelloWorld
        18: putfield      #5                  // Field aString:Ljava/lang/String;
        21: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 1: 0
        line 3: 4
        line 4: 9
        line 5: 15
}
SourceFile: "Test.java"
```

As you can see, the compiler still allocates the field properties.

So no, unused variables will still be allocated pointers (for Objects) and memory (for primitives).

Comment: This looks to be the definitive answer to me

Comment: But JustInTime compiler can and actually do this optimization. eg in disruptor special inheritance magic is used to pad contended field in cashline. see PaddedAtomicLong (http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.de/2011/08/false-sharing-java-7.html)
Not sure about public fields though.

Comment: @HuwJones  Thanks with a UPVOTE for your effort

Answer (score 2):

I've made some tests using brand new Java Object Layout tool (http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/) from OpenJDK. 
Tests show that at least on my 2 machines, JVM, moon phase, etc. JIT can't figure that some fields are unused and doesn't optimize them out.
But even if JIT **could**, it's not necessary that it actually **will** do particular optimization.
Here is the test:

```
public static long devNull;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    out.println(VM.current().details());

    Wasty wasty = new Wasty();
    Clean clean = new Clean();

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
        devNull += wasty.doSomething();
        devNull += clean.doSomething();
        if (i == 0 || i == 9_999_999) {
            pw.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(wasty).toFootprint());
            pw.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(clean).toFootprint());
        }
    }
    pw.close();
}
public class Wasty {
    private long _long;
    private double _double;
    private String _string;
    private long used;
    private int _int;
    private boolean _boolean;

    public long doSomething() {
        return used++;
    }
}
public class Clean {
    private long used;

    public long doSomething() {
        return used++;
    }
}
```

And the results are:

```
    # WARNING: Unable to attach Serviceability Agent. You can try again with escalated privileges. Two options: a) use -Djol.tryWithSudo=true to try with sudo; b) echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
    # Running 64-bit HotSpot VM.
    # Using compressed oop with 3-bit shift.
    # Using compressed klass with 3-bit shift.
    # WARNING | Compressed references base/shifts are guessed by the experiment!
    # WARNING | Therefore, computed addresses are just guesses, and ARE NOT RELIABLE.
    # WARNING | Make sure to attach Serviceability Agent to get the reliable addresses.
    # Objects are 8 bytes aligned.
    # Field sizes by type: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]
    # Array element sizes: 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8 [bytes]

    layout.Wasty@5f205aad footprint:
    COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
    1        48        48   layout.Wasty
    1                  48   (total)


    layout.Clean@2f410acfd footprint:
    COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
    1        24        24   layout.Clean
    1                  24   (total)


    layout.Wasty@5f205aad footprint:
    COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
    1        48        48   layout.Wasty
    1                  48   (total)


    layout.Clean@2f410acfd footprint:
    COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
    1        24        24   layout.Clean
    1                  24   (total)
```

So, in terms of **footprint** (memory performance) it **matters** that one have **unused fields** as they in fact consume memory and may corrupt layout of the object. The second point against unused fields is code smell already mentioned by Joop Eggen.

Comment: It usually matters in terms of speed, too, as unused fields take away memory bandwidth and waste cache space.